# Shortening repetitive (but long) code

Tags: jquery, html, repeat

I've looked into the different posts on shortening code, but I find it hard to apply it to my code. I'm still at a beginner -level and I just don't know how to start.

I have a function that will need to repeat 40 times. I've uploaded a print screen from what my function does, which is in jQuery with the jqPlot plugin.

It displays two data series, and the user is able to click on the graph to indicate what he thinks will be the next data point in the time series.

Every user will get 40 of these graphs. The code I currently have is a function that only displays graph 1. I would have to loop it so it would show all 40 graphs (40 different time series), but in a different order for every user (randomized). My first issue however, is to make it repeat without using repetitive code.
[image: Graph example]

edit: based on super-qua's reaction I now have the following code:

I define following global variables (I have limited myself for the moment to three data series,shortened view)

```
var index;
var promo1 = [0,81,102,..];
var s1 = [[0,301.961878917828],[1,287.301563144611],..,[50,285.689751451376]];
var promo2 = [0,184,0,..];
var s2 = [[0,286.723878917828],[1,444.439356046045]..,[50,323.874367563812]];
var promo3 = [0,196,0,..];
var s3 = [[0,250.478609608828],[1,416.973663811716],..,[50,335.79777763802]];
```

this is my function 'Run'

```
var Run = function(){
    // create divs
 var graph = $('<div id="GRAPH' +index +'"><h4> Click on the graph to indicate the expected sales numbers for time period 51 and 52 (in that order). </h4></div>');
 var chart = $('<div id="chart' +index +'" style="width:800px;height:450px"></div>');
 var info = $('<div id="info' +index +'"></div>');
 var proceed = $('<div id="proceed'+index+'"><b>To change your forecast</b>, simply click on the graph. </p><p> <b>To save your forecast</b>, click the button below. </p><p> <button type="button" id="save1">Save forecast for time period 51</button> </p><p> <button type="button" id="submit">Submit my forecast</button> </p>');
 // append them to the graph div
 $(chart).appendTo(graph);
 $(info).appendTo(graph);
 $(proceed).appendTo(graph);
 var promo = $(promo+index);
 var s = $(s+index);
 $(plot).appendTo(chart);

 var plot = $.jqplot('chart'+index, [promo[index], s[index]], {
        stackSeries: false,
        series: [
        {label:'Promotions',
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                barMargin: 12,
                barPadding: 0
                }
        },
        {label:'Sales', renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer, color:'grey', lineWidth: 2},
        ,
    {}
    ],   
            axesDefaults: {
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                angle: 0,
                fontSize: '8pt'

                }
                },
            axes: {
            xaxis: {
                tickInterval : 1,

                min: 0,
                max: 55
        },
            yaxis: {
                autoscale: true,
                min: 0
            }
        },
            cursor: {
                show: true,
                followMouse: true
            },
            legend: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer.min , 
                show: true,
                location: 'ne',
                placement: 'outside',
                marginRight: '50px'
            }
        });

 $(chart).bind('jqplotClick', function(event, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
 xax51_s = pointIndex.xaxis; 
 yax51_s = pointIndex.yaxis;
s[index].push([pointIndex.xaxis,pointIndex.yaxis]);
console.log("Seriesnr" +index + xax51_s + " - " + yax51_s);
myDataRef.push("Seriesnr" +index + xax51_s + " - " + yax51_s);
if (Math.round(xax51_s1) === 51) {
    $('#info1').html("Your sales forecast for time period 51 is " + Math.round(yax51_s1) + " units.");
    $('#proceed1').show();
    $('#submit1').hide();
    //add new datapoint and renew dataserie s1
    plot1.series[1].data = [[0,301.961878917828],[1,287.301563144611],[2,333.856817030694],..[50,285.689751451376],[xax51_s1,yax51_s1]];
    //fill in replot/redraw!
    plot1.drawSeries({},1); 
}
//if they click outside of the 51st time period:
else {
   alert("Please click on the correct grid line (period 51)"); 
}
 });

  $(graph).appendTo('body');
};
```

rest of the jquery is kept simple andincludes the loop:

```
$('div').hide();
   $("#INTRO").show();
   $("#Start").click(function(){
       $("#INTRO").hide();
       for(var index=0; index<4; index++){
         Run(index);
```

The issue I have now is that it doesn't seem to do anything. I get a blank page indicating that the divs are not working. I should see the title created for div "GRAPH", but it doesn't display. I also get the message from jqplot that no plot target was specified, although this is specified as 'chart'. Possibly this is also because the divs are not getting created.

Comment: So basically you want to render 40 different graphs in advance?

Comment: I already have all the necessary time series (so I have s1 = [0,300,245,..) and s2 = [365,256,254,..]) if that's what you mean. What I need is to find a way to show the first graph with time series 1. Then a new chart loads with a new time series (s2). once answered, then the next one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grabbing and updating super-qua's answer.

```
var promo = [], s = [];
for (i = 1; i < 41; i++) { //assuming that promo# and s# are both global variables.
    promo[i] = window["promo"+i];
    s[i] = window["s"+i];
}
var Run = function(index){
 // create your divs
 var graph = $('<div id="GRAPH' +index +'"><h4> Click on the graph to indicate the expected sales numbers for time period 51 and 52 (in that order). </h4></div>');
 var chart = $('<div id="chart' +index +'" style="width:800px;height:450px"></div>');
 var info = $('<div id="info' +index +'"></div>');

 // append them to the graph div
 $(chart).appendTo(graph);
 $(info).appendTo(graph);
 // add your proceed div the same way

 var plot = $.jqplot('chart' +index, [promo[index], s[index]], {
 //(I have taken out all the settings here for the series so it doesn't get too messy) 

 $(chart).bind('jqplotClick', function(event, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
 xax51_s = pointIndex.xaxis; // if you need to store the information for later use an array as well with xax51_s.push(pointIndex.xaxis)
 yax51_s = pointIndex.yaxis;

  // ... the rest of your code goes here

  // finally append the graph div to your DOM
  $(graph).appendTo('body') // replace body with whatever your element container is
}
```

I can only say is tha if .jqplot needs the divs to be already rendered on page this will not work, unless you render all the divs/charts/info in using the same loop but hide them otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be the problem indeed with jqplot, thanks for the tip. I have gone another route now because this one didn't seem viable..

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of possibilities to achieve this. 
I'd go with a function that takes the index as a parameter, creates the div for you, and appends it to the dom. If you can, you should use arrays for your data like `promo` and `s`.

It could look something like this (not tested - and just to give you an idea. so i leave some things out):

```
var Run = function(index){
     // create your divs
     var graph = $('<div id="GRAPH' +index +'"><h4> Click on the graph to indicate the expected sales numbers for time period 51 and 52 (in that order). </h4></div>');
     var chart = $('<div id="chart' +index +'" style="width:800px;height:450px"></div>');
     var info = $('<div id="info' +index +'"></div>');

     // append them to the graph div
     $(chart).appendTo(graph);
     $(info).appendTo(graph);
     // add your proceed div the same way

     // finally append the graph div to your DOM
     $(graph).appendTo('body') // replace body with whatever your element container is

     var plot = $.jqplot('chart' +index, [promo[index], s[index]], {
     //(I have taken out all the settings here for the series so it doesn't get too messy) 

     $(chart).bind('jqplotClick', function(event, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
     xax51_s = pointIndex.xaxis; // if you need to store the information for later use an array as well with xax51_s.push(pointIndex.xaxis)
     yax51_s = pointIndex.yaxis;

      // ... the rest of your code goes here
```

You can run this 40 times in a simple loop. For example

```
for(var i=0; i<40; i++){
   Run(i);
}
```

Note: I don't know about jqplot, but it might need you to append the graph prior to creating the plot.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

As updated above, move the `$(graph).appendTo('body')` before the `$.jqplot` line

This is what your arrays should look like

```
  var promo = [[0,81,102], [0,184,0], [0,196,0]];
  var s = [[[0,301.961878917828],[1,287.301563144611],[50,285.689751451376]], [[0,286.723878917828],[1,444.439356046045],[50,323.874367563812]], [[0,250.478609608828],[1,416.973663811716],[50,335.79777763802]]];
```

Then, there are two more things I noticed:

- You have one comma too many after the line `{label:'Sales', renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer, color:'grey', lineWidth: 2},`
- Get rid of the `var promo = $(promo+index);` - because you have promo already

Comment: Thanks @super-qua . I made the changes, but it doesn't seem to be creating the divs..

Comment: can you debug it and see if there is any syntax error preventing it from creating the divs?

Comment: Firebug only says: Error: No plot target specified (same as netbeans debugger). nothing on the divs..

Comment: okay, so this seems to have something to do with jqplot not finding your div. try to append the graph before you call `$.jqplot()`

Comment: I've tried      $(plot).appendTo(graph);     $(plot).appendTo(chart); $(chart).appendTo(graph); .. nothing. So I think it might have something to do with the chart-div not being there. for instance, if the 'graph'div would have been created, I should see the title standing there - even if the jqplot would not be working. I just don't get it..

Comment: I have run the code line by line and the graph etc divs are not changing and the promo+index also doesn't work so by the time you get to the plot = line the variables are not properly defined. There's no chart+index, there's no promo+index and there's no s+index..

Comment: You might want to transfer all s1, s2, s3, etc. and promo1, promo2, promo3, etc. variables into the s and promo array that super-qua's function wants.

Comment: You should try to append the graph to the DOM prior to calling `$.jqplot`, which is done by the line `$(graph).appendTo('body')`. I moved the line for you in the code. Also @kyerie is right, that's what I meant with using arrays for `promo` and `s`

Comment: okay so I ran your code, and with some minor tweaks I was able to plot the graphs. See my update.